# Indefinite integral of $\arctan(x)$, why consider $1\cdot dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm supposed to take the integral of $\arctan(x)$ but get the wrong answer. I know my answer is wrong because I'm supposed to do integration by parts and consider the integral to be $ \int {\arctan(x) \cdot 1 dx} $. However, my question is WHY do I consider it to be $ \arctan(x) \cdot 1 dx $ and take these parts:

$$u = \arctan(x)$$

$$du = \frac {1} {x^2+1} $$

$$dv = dx$$

$$v = x?$$

For example, if I do $ \int {x^2 dx} $ I don't have to do integration by parts of $\int {x^2 \cdot 1  dx}$?

This question became really messy so here's a TLDR: Why do I consider $\int {\arctan(x) dx}$ to be equal to $\int {\arctan(x) 1 dx}$?

Comment: Integration by parts allows you to transform an unknown integral to a new one that you might know. With $x \mapsto x^2$ no need to do it, you already know the answer, but not for $arctan(x)$. So you can do that in order to make $1/(1+x^2)$ appears.

Comment: I see, so it's basically a trick to make the integral easier/doable? There isn't any rule that requires me to do it in some cases?

Comment: That's it. That's the easier way to compute this kind of integral, as functions like $x \mapsto xe^{x}$, $x \mapsto x \sin(x)$ or even $x \mapsto ln(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a trick to apply the integration by parts $\int fg'= fg -\int f'g$ with $g'=1$.

Note that a similar trick is used for

$$\int \log x dx=\int 1\cdot \log x dx= x\log x - \int x\cdot \frac1x dx$$

we assume $g'(x)=1$ as such that $g(x)=x$.

Comment: Okay, so basically I could take $ \int {x^2 *1 dx} $ (or any integral) and do integration by parts IF it would make it easier/doable for me? There isn't any rule that requires me to do it in this case for arctan(x)?

Comment: @gbgult Exactly $f(x)=1\cdot f(x)$ always holds!